# How to filter ValueList Of A Column When dropdown Of it fires based on other Column value in Jaus Gridex?

Tags: c#, janus, gridex

I have a janus gridex on my form. one column is multi column combo and is fill of cities.
i have another column of countries.
i want showing that cities belong to specific country for each row when user drop downs city column.
countries an cities is in dataset.
i fill value list of cities but dont know how to filter it for each row without destorying other rows city cokumn. becouse behind of city is City ID and value member , dispaley member are user.
thank

Comment: Hi , Did you try something? If we see some (not working) code, it is easier to help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the EditingCell event in the grid.

In the EditingCell event you can build up your own list of items for the ValueList, and assign it to the EditValueList property of the column through EditingCellEventArgs object.